# How to rotate an element around a line other than X=0,Y=0 and Z=0 using CSS3?

Tags: math, css

I created this **[page](http://jsbin.com/ofimij/2)** for better understanding the question. As you can see using CSS3 we can rotate an element around the X,Y or Z axis using `transform: rotate[XYZ](M deg/rad)`.

But I'm looking for a function to rotate the element on any given line. For example, rotating the element on `x=y` line. or even more complex `y=2x+3`.

If you don't understand it please hold a paper in hand and flip it from its two far corners (for `y=x` or `y=-x`). or look at this picture.

[image]

[image]

I'm guessing it would be combination of two rotations, but I don't know how to calculate the rotations.

**Update:**

I didn't know there is a `rotate3d` function for CSS `transform`. this function accepts four arguments `rx`, `ry`, `rz` and `deg`. I feel that would be very helpful for this problem.

Other thing is when we change `translate[X,Y,Z]` it actually changing the origin of rotation. That mean if you want to rotate around `Y=10px` you should change the `translateZ` to `10px`

**Update2:**

My Actual goal is creating a tool to apply CSS transform property using a GUI. as you can see in my jsbin file. I want to extend it to whatever `transform` possible you can do. One of them is rotation. I'm sure it's possible to rotate an element around other lines than `x=0`... but I don't know how can I do the calculation. For example rotation 45deg around `Y` and 45deg around `Z` is same as rotating 45 deg around `x=y`. I need a solution for all lines in the space.

Comment: All rotations on any axis can be defined as rotations on the X, Y and Z axes - making this simply a math question. Wikipedia has [something to start with](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle). :)

Comment: Are you trying to create an M-theory model with javascript? :)

Comment: Any line in 3D space can be an axis for rotation. Just think x=y line. Please reopen my question. I will add more detail

Comment: We are not in 3D space. HTML documents are 2D in nature, so all you can rotate around is a point. [3D transforms](http://www.webkit.org/blog/386/3d-transforms/) are a different thing altogether...

Comment: When you say "rotate" do you really mean rotation through an arbitrary angle (so that the resulting figure can lie out of the plane) or do you simple mean flip-it-over (i.e. *reflection*) across the line. The latter case is considerable simpler.

Comment: a flip is a 180degree rotation

Comment: Yes it is, but it is also amenable to simpler treatment than arbitrary rotations around a arbitrary line, and your actual goal here remains utterly mysterious to me.

Comment: My Actual goal is creating a tool to apply CSS transform property using a GUI. as you can see in my jsbin file. I want to extend it to whatever transform possible you can do. One of them is rotation. I'm sure it's possible to rotate an element around other lines than x=0... but I don't know how can I do the calculation. For example rotation 45deg around Y and 45deg around Z is same as rotating 45 deg around x=y. I need a solution for all lines in the space. Was I clear?

Comment: No. Because your display space is 2D and the resulting figure will be out of plane, so you also need to specify a projection. For a parallel projection this remain about as easy as reflecting. On a side note, I treat having to go off site and read code to understand the question the same as *tl;dr*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution for question I'm asking is css transform function, `rotate3d`. Using this function we could rotate DOM elements around any line in 3D space.

This function accepts four arguments that three first are `x`, `y` and `z` and last one is rotation. As I understand how this function work you can translate your line linear algebra function into `rotate3d` like this:

If you have a line function like `1x + 2y + 3z = 0` and want to rotate your element 30 degree then you should apply this css property to element; `transform: rotate3d(1, 2, 3, 30deg);`.

I've created [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen/25dhk/6/) little app to demonstrate  how `rotate3d` works.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest reading the introduction to the article 
[Rotation About an Arbitrary Axis in 3 Dimensions](http://inside.mines.edu/~gmurray/ArbitraryAxisRotation/) .  The basics are:

```
(1) Translate space so that the rotation axis passes through the origin.
(2) Rotate space about the z axis so that the rotation axis lies in the xz plane.
(3) Rotate space about the y axis so that the rotation axis lies along the z axis.
(4) Perform the desired rotation by θ about the z axis.
(5) Apply the inverse of step (3).
(6) Apply the inverse of step (2).
(7) Apply the inverse of step (1).
```

Answer (score 0):

I beleive I understand what you mean. So, if you know Photoshop, when you rotate an image, you can choose an anchor point. This is the same idea. So you add the code rotation-point: 50% 50% to the class. Only issue is, rotation point isn't accepted in any browser yet, but soon will be. I thought you should know that this will eventually be a possibility. [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_rotation-point.asp) for more

Comment: I don't want to rotate around a point. CSS3 transform-origin is supported in any modern browser. rotation point seems to be rejected

Comment: I just said it probably will be unsupported. But you need to use %'s probably